# Capistrano: trying to run rake db:seed on remote server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I'm trying to run my seed file on a remote server using capistrano. My deploy is OK, so there is no issue there. Here is the code for running the seed file in config/deploy.rb

```
namespace :seed do
  desc "Run a task on a remote server."
  # run like: cap staging rake:invoke task=a_certain_task  
  task :default do
    run("cd #{deploy_to}/current; /usr/bin/env bundle exec rake #{ENV['db:seed']} RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}")
  end
end
```

I am evoking this task by running 'cap seed'.

Whats weird is it looks like tests are running when I run this..[HERE](http://pastie.org/8611184) is a snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem is with #{ENV['db:seed']} part. Isn't it should be just db:seed. The eniviroment variable db:seed doesn't exist so You are calling a pure rake command.

Try this:

```
run("cd #{deploy_to}/current; /usr/bin/env bundle exec rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env}")
```

Comment: Boom! That did it...thanx pk.